# What's Ubuntu package for virtualgl-libs

Tags: apt, bumblebee, playonlinux

I stumble upon an error while trying to run League of Legends (through PlayOnLinux) with optirun. I got these errors :

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libdlfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'librrfaker.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

As stated in the doc, I try to check if the `virtualgl-libs:i386` package is installed. However, it seems that this package does not exist anymore or its name has changed. I'd like to know its new name, could you help me ?

I've found a package called `virtualgl`. But when I run `sudo apt-get install virtualgl:i386`, it returns an error saying that (approx translation from french) :

```
No version of the virtualgl:i386 package is available, but it exists in the database, 
This means that the package is missing, obsolete or only available through an other source.
No version of the "virtualgl:i386" package can be installed
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

The package virtualgl doesnt exists. Bumblebee stable ppa contains it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualgl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-cache search virtualgl

bumblebee - NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
primus - client-side GPU offloading for NVIDIA Optimus
```

While running apt-cache search on virtualgl,it shows the above two packages.So installing any one of the above two packages will install virtualgl.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest .deb from [the official builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/), and then install it as:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualgl-<whatever>.deb
```

It gets installed under the directory: `/opt/VirtualGL/`

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu 14.04 and newer

```
sudo apt-get install primus
```

see

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee
- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/Hybrid-Grafikkarten/primus/